# How to fit a Gaussian to a pair correlation function?

Tags: spatstat

I am fairly new to R and try using the spatstat package to analyze single-molecule microscopy data.

To find the average/dominant size of the observed clusters of points I convert my data into a 'ppp' and run a pair correlation function (pcf.ppp). I understood that the dominant cluster size is the sigma of a Gaussian fit to this function.

However, I have no clue how to fit a Gaussian function and to extract the sigma. Any help is much appreciated!

This is my code so far:

```
MyPattern <- ppp(Loc[,1],Loc[,2],c(10000,25000),c(10000,25000))
plot(MyPattern)
Test <- pcf.ppp(MyPattern)
plot(Test)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `kppm` in the `spatstat` package does this. Just type

```
kppm(MyPattern)
```

and read the cluster scale parameter `sigma`. (Formally this is known as the "Thomas model"). To automate this you could do

```
fit <- kppm(MyPattern)
parameters(fit)
```

For further information see Chapter 12 in [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)